# Formatting type by fallback to pointer with fmt library

Tags: c++, c++14, fmt

I am try using

```cpp
fmt::format("Expected : '{}' vs. '{}'", getDataOrPointer(rA), getDataOrPointer(rB));
```

where `getDataOrPointer` should return a `void` pointer (which can always be formatted) or the default value when a formatter exists:

```cpp
//! Return the type if a `fmt::formatter` exists.
template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if_t<hasFormatter<std::decay<T>, char>>* = 0>
decltype(auto) getDataOrPointer(const T& rData)
{
    return rData;
}

//! Return a void-Pointer if no `fmt::formatter` exists.
template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if_t<!hasFormatter<std::decay<T>, char>>* = 0>
const void* getDataOrPointer(const T& rData)
{
    return static_cast<const void*>(&rData);
}
```

I dont know how to write: `hasFormatter<T,char>` to check if it can be formatted or not by the `fmt` library?. I want this fallback only locally not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fmt::has_formatter`, quoting https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/1369:

> `has_formatter<T, Context>` tells you that type `T` has a `formatter` specialization for `Context` (context basically specifies character and output iterator types) and it can be used with SFINAE. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/pCD14x. The main caveat is that types with implicit conversion can be formattable but not have a `formatter` specialization.

Comment: See https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/1369#event-4248590915